# How to update the Nuget Package in the Server using MSDeploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, msdeploy

We are using Jenkins and MSDeploy tool to deploy our .Net MVC Project, In Local We have updated the EPPLUS Nuget Package version to 4.1 from 2.3 and its working fine but when am pushing the change its failing with the error like it cannot find the EPPLUS 4.1

And the error message is below

D:\servers\jenkins\jobs\TEST\workspace.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : Unable to find version '4.1.1' of package 'EPPlus'. [D:\servers\jenkins\jobs\TEST\workspace\NIDD\MYProj.csproj]

D:\servers\jenkins\jobs\TEST\workspace.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error MSB3073: The command ""...nuget\NuGet.exe" install "D:\servers\jenkins\jobs\TEST\workspace\MYProj\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "..\ "" exited with code 1. [D:\servers\jenkins\jobs\TEST\workspace\MYProj\MYProj.csproj]

Comment: Learn how to put a NuGet.config file in your repo to lock down the NuGet sources. The issue simply reflects the wrong sources are there by default.

Comment: @Lex li, Nuget.Config file is already there in Repo and I checked one more thing from the server machine Nuget.org site itself not reachable even ping is not happening. Is it causing the problem? As of now I have fixed it by copying the new DLL in Lib folder of my project and sent it to Repo. Now its not downloading since already there as Local copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of try I decided to put the single DLL(EPPLUS 4.1) into my repository directly then pushed that into repository so now Nuget is not trying to download so no other error like cannot connect.
But if you have more number of DLL files then avoid this method because it will increase the size of the Repository.